# error zipaligning apk file

Tags: android, eclipse

So I have my project FILES. And I want to zipalign an apk file. I cant do it in Eclipse, or  Android studio this comes up:

```
Android Source Generator: [Tiber] Package is not specified in AndroidManifest.xml
```

Anyone know how I can fix this or know an alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the zipalign tool with your Eclipse installaton. You can zipalign your apk manually by running the following command:

```
zipalign -v notaligned.apk zipaligned.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should declare the android version which you are using in your `manifest.xml` file.

For example:

```
android:targetSdkVersion="18"
```